# How do I sign in to SQL Server locally

Tags: sql-server, windows

I installed SQL Server 2014 on my win8 pc at home so I can play around with it to do basic stuff like `create database dbname;` and add people. But I get a prompt to sign in and I can't. I also changed server name to `.` still nothing what do I need to do?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibu5I.png

Comment: what happens when you click connect?

Comment: If you installed with all defaults, then your server/instance name will be `.\SQLEXPRESS` if you installed SQL Server 2014 **Express** (the free edition), or it will just be `.` if you installed any other edition. Then just use "Windows Authentication" to connect to your server

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1329/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-2014-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx)

To connect to your SQL Server 2014 database using SQL Server Management Studio:

Open SQL Server Management Studio, the Connect to Server window will open. Select/enter the following:

- Server Type: Database Engine
- Server Name: [The SQL server name found in Control Panel: Database Management > MS SQL 2014]
- Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
- Login: [SQL 2014 Login name]
- Password: [SQL 2014 Password]

Click the Options button. Under connection properties, check the box that reads Encrypt connection.

Click connect.

Comment: i re ran sql server 2014 express and it worked but thx. sure it will help some one else